# Increasing clickable area of ImageView

Tags: android, android-imageview, android-relativelayout

I have created a `RelativeLayout` shown below as part of a toolbar. The layout consists of two images and a thin line below the images. For the two images I have increased the width because then the clickable area is wider. A screenshot (Android Studio) how it looks like is shown at the bottom.

The problem now is that I can't control the size of the image (the image is just placed in the center). How can I fix the actual size of the image to 25 x 25 dp and still extend the clickable area to the left and right of the image by let's say 70 dp and at the bottom and top of the image by 10 dp?

```
<RelativeLayout  xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:id="@+id/keyboard_toolbar"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_gravity="bottom"
    android:orientation="horizontal">

    <View
        android:id="@+id/keyboard_toolbar_line"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="1dp"
        android:layout_below="@id/privacyButton"
        android:layout_marginBottom="5dp"
        android:background="#c0c0c0"/>

    <ImageView
        android:id="@+id/privacyButton"
        android:layout_width="100dp"
        android:layout_alignParentStart="true"
        android:layout_height="35dp"
        android:scaleType="center"
        android:layout_marginStart="30dp"
        android:src="@drawable/research_ic_lock_open_dark" />

    <ImageView
        android:id="@+id/ratingButton"
        android:layout_width="100dp"
        android:layout_alignParentEnd="true"
        android:layout_height="35dp"
        android:scaleType="center"
        android:layout_marginEnd="30dp"
        android:src="@drawable/ic_star" />

</RelativeLayout >
```

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You may think of wrapping it in a `LinearLayout` that has the exact extra width & height you want, and keep your image in 25x25dp; then add the click listener to the `LinearLayout` instead of the `ImageView`

sample for one image:

```
<LinearLayout
    android:layout_width="140dp"
    android:gravity="center"
    android:layout_height="35dp">

    <ImageView
        android:id="@+id/privacyButton"
        android:layout_width="25dp"
        android:layout_height="25dp"
        android:layout_alignParentStart="true"
        android:layout_marginStart="30dp"
        android:scaleType="center"
        android:src="@drawable/quarter_circle" />

</LinearLayout>
```

I just added arbitrary values for the `LinearLayout`, for the width, as you need 70dp to the right and left so the total is 140.

Answer (score 1):

If I'm not mistaken, this is your solution.

You first put a parent layout and then put the `ImageView` inside it.
Then `onclicklistener` on the parent.

```
 <RelativeLayout  xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
        android:id="@+id/keyboard_toolbar"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_gravity="bottom"
        android:orientation="horizontal">

        <View
            android:id="@+id/keyboard_toolbar_line"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="1dp"
            android:layout_below="@id/privacyButton"
            android:layout_marginBottom="5dp"
            android:background="#c0c0c0"/>

        <RelativeLayout
            android:layout_width="100dp"
            android:layout_height="35dp">
            <ImageView
                android:id="@+id/privacyButton"
                android:layout_width="35dp"
                android:layout_alignParentStart="true"
                android:layout_height="35dp"
                android:scaleType="center"
                android:layout_marginStart="30dp"
                android:src="@drawable/research_ic_lock_open_dark" />
        </RelativeLayout>
    <RelativeLayout
        android:layout_width="100dp"
        android:layout_height="35dp">

        <ImageView
            android:id="@+id/ratingButton"
            android:layout_width="35dp"
            android:layout_alignParentEnd="true"
            android:layout_height="35dp"
            android:scaleType="center"
            android:layout_marginEnd="30dp"
            android:src="@drawable/ic_star" />
    </RelativeLayout>

    </RelativeLayout>
```